# Java: Data structure for minimum spanning tree

Tags: java, prims-algorithm

My project is to implement minimum spanning tree using java. I aim to use Prim's algorithm to do the task.

The definition of the graph is G = (V, E) where V is the set of pins, E is the set of possible interconnections between pairs of pins, and for each edge (u,v) in E we have a weigh w(u,v) specifying the cost to connect u and v.

My idea is to use two hashmaps. First would have pin as a key and a list of neighbours as value. The second hashmap would take list of edge (u,v) as a key and the value would be its weight.

What do you think is the best way to store the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphs are generally (without regard to the algorithm used with those graphs) stored as either :

- adjacency lists,
- adjacency matrices,
- incidence lists,
- incidence matrices.

All have their advantages and disadvantages concerning memory usage and time required to traverse them. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29#Representations) has a great write-up on graph representations in computers.

Comment: So let's assume I go with the adjacency list, it would still be viable to use the second hashmap to contain the weight of each pair?

Comment: Sure. :) As long as you don't forget to update that extra structure, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Look on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm#Time_complexity). You have different data structures available as well as the inherited complexities

Answer (score 0):

For both Kruskal’s and Prim’s minimum spanning tree algorithms adjacency-list representation of the graph is enough. It's more efficient in memory usage than matrice's approach. So it's a good choise in your case.